# How to use \begin{cases} inside table?

Tags: tables, footnotes, cases

When I am using \begin{cases}, the content under the 1st column of this table is very long and it can not be broken into two lines using linebreak.
[image]

And this table becomes very big, so it does not fit in A4 size paper. When I use \small or \footnotesize, then it fits in A4 size paper.

[image]

Is there any way to get this table which will  fit in A4 size paper without using  \small or \footnotesize?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,physics,multirow}
\usepackage[
width=18.5cm,
height=26cm,
heightrounded
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{ADD CAPTION }
    %\small
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l @{}}
        \toprule
        \bf{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS} & \bf{SSSSSSSSSS}& \bf{ SSSSSSS}  \\ 
        \midrule
        
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & ssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases} 
            a &\text{when sth}\\
            b &\text{when sth else} \\
            c &\text{when elsewhere;}
        \end{cases}
        $
        \\ \addlinespace
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases} 
            a &\text{when sth}\\
            b &\text{when sth else} \\
            c &\text{when elsewhere;}
        \end{cases}
        $
        \\ \addlinespace
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & ssssssssssssssssssssss& sssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases} 
            a &\text{when sth}\\
            b &\text{when sth else} \\
            c &\text{when elsewhere;}
        \end{cases}
        $
        \\ \addlinespace
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & sssssssssssssssssss & sssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases} 
            a &\text{when sth}\\
            b &\text{when sth else} \\
            c &\text{when elsewhere;}
        \end{cases}
        $
        \\ \addlinespace
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & sssssssssssss& sssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases} 
            a &\text{when sth}\\
            b &\text{when sth else} \\
            c &\text{when elsewhere;}
        \end{cases}
        $
        
        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Again, if I am not using `\begin{cases}`, then I am able to break the 1st column contents into two small rows, but still, the table is not organized. (attached here)
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,physics,multirow}
\usepackage[
width=18.5cm,
height=26cm,
heightrounded
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{add caption }
    
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
        \toprule%[0.07cm]
        %   \hline\hline\\
        
        
        \bf{Ssssssss} & \bf{ssssssss}& \bf{ssssssssssss}  & \bf{ssssssssssss}  \\ 
        
        \midrule
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
         $\qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG $ \\
        &&& $\qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG $  \\
        &&& $\qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF $   \\ 
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $\qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG $ \\
        &&& $\qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG $  \\
        &&& $\qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF $   \\
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $\qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG $ \\
        &&& $\qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG $  \\
        &&& $\qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF $   \\
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $\qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG $ \\
        &&& $\qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG $  \\
        &&& $\qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF $   \\
        
        %   \hline\hline
        \bottomrule%[0.07cm]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And also the table is still unorganized if I use `\begin{cases}` (attached).

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,physics,multirow}
\usepackage[
width=18.5cm,
height=26cm,
heightrounded
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{add caption }
    
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l}
        \toprule%[0.07cm]
        %   \hline\hline\\
        
        
        \bf{Ssssssss} & \bf{ssssssss}& \bf{ssssssssssss}  & \bf{ssssssssssss}  \\ 
        
        \midrule
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases}
         \qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG  \\
         \qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG   \\
         \qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF 
        \end{cases}
        $   \\ 
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases}
            \qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG  \\
            \qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG   \\
            \qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF 
        \end{cases}
        $   \\ 
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases}
            \qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG  \\
            \qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG   \\
            \qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF 
        \end{cases}
        $   \\ 
        
        \multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) & sssssssssssssssssss& ssssssssssssssssss&
        $
        \begin{cases}
            \qty\big{x,y}_{H_{1}}=GFGG  \\
            \qty\big{y,z}_{H_{1}}=FGFGFG   \\
            \qty\big{z,x}_{H_{1}}=FGGF 
        \end{cases}
        $   \\ 
        
        %   \hline\hline
        \bottomrule%[0.07cm]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I need to use `\begin{cases}`, but not to use `\footnotesize`. What to do?